# Why does Redirect() function tries to redirect me inside the same controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm building a return URL by concatenating many string variables, but for the sake of testing, I used a test string.

It works perfectly in the login function of the account controller :

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    /* irrelevant code lines */

    return Redirect( "SuiviFinancier/Niveau2?unitAdm=012"    /*returnUrl*/);
}
```

this redirect to the right route : **/SuiviFinancier/Niveau2?unitAdm=012**

But that redirect function used in another controller, makes it automatically add the controller name before the string, exemple :

```
public class paramsVisuelController : Controller
{
    
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Options(ParamsVisuel model)
    {
        return Redirect( "SuiviFinancier/Niveau2?unitAdm=012" );

    }
}
```

The output route here is : **/paramsVisuel/SuiviFinancier/Niveau2?unitAdm=012**

Why is that ? MVC is adding the controller name before my string ? But I don't want that. It is a complete route including the controller so why would I want the current controller name to be added before it ? It's non-sens.

> Description : HTTP 404.
>
> URL demandée: /paramsVisuel/SuiviFinancier/Niveau2

Comment: Try `return Redirect( "~/SuiviFinancier/Niveau2?unitAdm=012" );`

Comment: Try starting with slash e.g. "/SuiviFinancier/Niveau2?unitAdm=012" or "~/SuiviFinancier/Niveau2?unitAdm=012".

Comment: HA HELL, it was the "/" missing... like @PauloCastilho 's first suggestion. Feel free to make this an answer.

Comment: If this is a MVC application and this url is a controller/action, you should consider using redirect like this RedirectToAction("Niveau2", "SuiviFinancier", new { unitAdm = 012 });

Comment: I know, that's what i usually do, but this time, i was building the url with a concatenation of many string var. So it was easier this way

Comment: [`RedirectToAction(string, string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Controller_RedirectToAction_System_String_System_String_)

Comment: @Liam ... I'm building the return url with many variables, i simplified it here so you guys can answer more easily. Believe me i found no other way and this was the best solution for my current needs. Downvotes won't make me delete my question this time, because it's a good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, one should use this function for redirection :

```
RedirectToAction("Niveau2", "SuiviFinancier", new { unitAdm = 012 });
```

Which is the classic MVC way to redirect to an action in a controller.

But if, for some reason, you need the `redirect()` function to work properly, don't forget to begin your string whit a slash if it's a complete path :

```
return Redirect( "/SuiviFinancier/Niveau2?unitAdm=012");
```

or a tilt and a slash :

```
return Redirect( "~/SuiviFinancier/Niveau2?unitAdm=012");
```